# Google Sheet Slicers "Set current filters as default" Does Not Save

Tags: google-sheets, slicers

I am unable to set slicer filter settings as default so that when I close and re-open the sheet the default filters are still in place.
[image]

In the docs they show that setting current filters as default is an option, but when I set those and refresh or re-open the sheet the filters are not saved. Has anyone else come across this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since this does not look like the expected behavior for the Google Sheet Slicers, I suggest you file an issue on **Issue Tracker** [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/) and provide all the requested details.

#### Reference

- [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)